# overlapping labels in flot pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot, pie-chart

I use jquery flot for my pie charts and I have a problem with overlapping 
labels when the pie chart pieces are very small. Is there a good 
solution for that?

My pie chart:

```
series: { 
                pie: { 
                    show: true, 
                    radius: 1, 
                    label: { 
                        show: true, 
                        radius: 5/8, 
                        formatter: function(label, series){ 
                            return '<div style="font-size:12pt;text-  align:center;padding:2px;color:black;margin-left:-80%;margin-  top:-20%;">'+label+'<br/>'+Math.round(series.percent)+'%</div>'; 
                        }, 
                        background: { opacity: 0.5 } 
                    } 
                } 
            }, 
            legend: { 
                show: false 
            }
```

Thanks, Arshavski Alexander.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A solution from Flot's Google code issues by **Marshall Leggett**([link](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=530)):

> I've found that it seems common for **pie labels to overlap** in smaller
>   pie charts making them unreadable, particularly if several slices have
>   small percentage values.  This is with the jquery.flot.pie plugin.
>   Please see attached images.  I've worked around this with the addition
>   of an anti-collision routine in the label rendering code.  I'm
>   attaching a copy of the revised plugin as well.  See **lines 472-501**,
>   particularly the new functions getPositions() and comparePositions(). 
>   This is based in part on Šime Vidas' DOM-element collision detection
>   code.  Something like this might be a nice addition to the pie
>   library.

[image: pie labels overlapping]
[image: pie labels overlapping fixed]

long story short:

1. In jquery.flot.pie.js and **after** the line **463** that contains:

   `label.css('left', labelLeft);`

add the following code:

```
// check to make sure that the label doesn't overlap one of the other labels
var label_pos = getPositions(label);
for(var j=0; j<labels.length; j++)
{
var tmpPos = getPositions(labels[j]);
var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(label_pos[0], tmpPos[0]);
var verticalMatch = comparePositions(label_pos[1], tmpPos[1]);                  
var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;                           
if(match)
{
    var newTop = tmpPos[1][0] - (label.height() +1 );
    label.css('top', newTop);
    labelTop = newTop;
}       
}

function getPositions(box) {
        var $box = $(box);
        var pos = $box.position();
        var width = $box.width();
        var height = $box.height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
}

function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
        var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
}
labels.push(label);
```

2. Add the following to `drawLabels()` and you are done:

   `var labels = [];`

Comment: This is 2015 and I am facing the same issue with Flot. Your solution is nice but I install the lib via bower. Doesn't seem like a good idea to tinker with the source.

Comment: This is 2017 and it worked. I left an example in
https://jsfiddle.net/shizus/1j4djqLx/2/ any idea why they are not fixing this oficially?

Answer (score 8):

you could try hiding some of the labels under a certain percentage:

```
pie: { 
    label: {
         threshold: 0.1
    }
}
```

See graph / example 6 on http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html

Answer (score 1):

I was using a modified version of flot.pie with the possibility to add gradients as fillstyle.
So i took the version linked by @Gabo Lato and merged the collision check with my own version.
Here is the result:

```
(function($) {

// Maximum redraw attempts when fitting labels within the plot

var REDRAW_ATTEMPTS = 10;

// Factor by which to shrink the pie when fitting labels within the plot

var REDRAW_SHRINK = 0.95;

function init(plot) {

    var canvas = null,
        target = null,
        options = null,
        maxRadius = null,
        centerLeft = null,
        centerTop = null,
        processed = false,
        ctx = null;

    // interactive variables

    var highlights = [];

    // add hook to determine if pie plugin in enabled, and then perform necessary operations

    plot.hooks.processOptions.push(function(plot, options) {
        if (options.series.pie.show) {

            options.grid.show = false;

            // set labels.show

            if (options.series.pie.label.show == "auto") {
                if (options.legend.show) {
                    options.series.pie.label.show = false;
                } else {
                    options.series.pie.label.show = true;
                }
            }

            // set radius

            if (options.series.pie.radius == "auto") {
                if (options.series.pie.label.show) {
                    options.series.pie.radius = 3/4;
                } else {
                    options.series.pie.radius = 1;
                }
            }

            // ensure sane tilt

            if (options.series.pie.tilt > 1) {
                options.series.pie.tilt = 1;
            } else if (options.series.pie.tilt < 0) {
                options.series.pie.tilt = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    plot.hooks.bindEvents.push(function(plot, eventHolder) {
        var options = plot.getOptions();
        if (options.series.pie.show) {
            if (options.grid.hoverable) {
                eventHolder.unbind("mousemove").mousemove(onMouseMove);
            }
            if (options.grid.clickable) {
                eventHolder.unbind("click").click(onClick);
            }
        }
    });

    plot.hooks.processDatapoints.push(function(plot, series, data, datapoints) {
        var options = plot.getOptions();
        if (options.series.pie.show) {
            processDatapoints(plot, series, data, datapoints);
        }
    });

    plot.hooks.drawOverlay.push(function(plot, octx) {
        var options = plot.getOptions();
        if (options.series.pie.show) {
            drawOverlay(plot, octx);
        }
    });

    plot.hooks.draw.push(function(plot, newCtx) {
        var options = plot.getOptions();
        if (options.series.pie.show) {
            draw(plot, newCtx);
        }
    });

    function processDatapoints(plot, series, datapoints) {
        if (!processed) {
            processed = true;
            canvas = plot.getCanvas();
            target = $(canvas).parent();
            options = plot.getOptions();
            plot.setData(combine(plot.getData()));
        }
    }

    function combine(data) {

        var total = 0,
            combined = 0,
            numCombined = 0,
            color = options.series.pie.combine.color,
            newdata = [];

        // Fix up the raw data from Flot, ensuring the data is numeric

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

            var value = data[i].data;

            // If the data is an array, we'll assume that it's a standard
            // Flot x-y pair, and are concerned only with the second value.

            // Note how we use the original array, rather than creating a
            // new one; this is more efficient and preserves any extra data
            // that the user may have stored in higher indexes.

            if ($.isArray(value) && value.length == 1) {
                value = value[0];
            }

            if ($.isArray(value)) {
                // Equivalent to $.isNumeric() but compatible with jQuery < 1.7
                if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value[1])) && isFinite(value[1])) {
                    value[1] = +value[1];
                } else {
                    value[1] = 0;
                }
            } else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value)) {
                value = [1, +value];
            } else {
                value = [1, 0];
            }

            data[i].data = [value];
        }

        // Sum up all the slices, so we can calculate percentages for each

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            total += data[i].data[0][1];
        }

        // Count the number of slices with percentages below the combine
        // threshold; if it turns out to be just one, we won't combine.

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var value = data[i].data[0][1];
            if (value / total <= options.series.pie.combine.threshold) {
                combined += value;
                numCombined++;
                if (!color) {
                    color = data[i].color;
                }
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var value = data[i].data[0][1];
            if (numCombined < 2 || value / total > options.series.pie.combine.threshold) {
                newdata.push(
                    $.extend(data[i], {     /* extend to allow keeping all other original data values
                                               and using them e.g. in labelFormatter. */
                        data: [[1, value]],
                        color: data[i].color,
                        label: data[i].label,
                        angle: value * Math.PI * 2 / total,
                        percent: value / (total / 100)
                    })
                );
            }
        }

        if (numCombined > 1) {
            newdata.push({
                data: [[1, combined]],
                color: color,
                label: options.series.pie.combine.label,
                angle: combined * Math.PI * 2 / total,
                percent: combined / (total / 100)
            });
        }

        return newdata;
    }

    function draw(plot, newCtx) {

        if (!target) {
            return; // if no series were passed
        }

        var canvasWidth = plot.getPlaceholder().width(),
            canvasHeight = plot.getPlaceholder().height(),
            legendWidth = target.children().filter(".legend").children().width() || 0;

        ctx = newCtx;

        // WARNING: HACK! REWRITE THIS CODE AS SOON AS POSSIBLE!

        // When combining smaller slices into an 'other' slice, we need to
        // add a new series.  Since Flot gives plugins no way to modify the
        // list of series, the pie plugin uses a hack where the first call
        // to processDatapoints results in a call to setData with the new
        // list of series, then subsequent processDatapoints do nothing.

        // The plugin-global 'processed' flag is used to control this hack;
        // it starts out false, and is set to true after the first call to
        // processDatapoints.

        // Unfortunately this turns future setData calls into no-ops; they
        // call processDatapoints, the flag is true, and nothing happens.

        // To fix this we'll set the flag back to false here in draw, when
        // all series have been processed, so the next sequence of calls to
        // processDatapoints once again starts out with a slice-combine.
        // This is really a hack; in 0.9 we need to give plugins a proper
        // way to modify series before any processing begins.

        processed = false;

        // calculate maximum radius and center point

        maxRadius =  Math.min(canvasWidth, canvasHeight / options.series.pie.tilt) / 2;
        centerTop = canvasHeight / 2 + options.series.pie.offset.top;
        centerLeft = canvasWidth / 2;

        if (options.series.pie.offset.left == "auto") {
            if (options.legend.position.match("w")) {
                centerLeft += legendWidth / 2;
            } else {
                centerLeft -= legendWidth / 2;
            }
            if (centerLeft < maxRadius) {
                centerLeft = maxRadius;
            } else if (centerLeft > canvasWidth - maxRadius) {
                centerLeft = canvasWidth - maxRadius;
            }
        } else {
            centerLeft += options.series.pie.offset.left;
        }

        var slices = plot.getData(),
            attempts = 0;

        // Keep shrinking the pie's radius until drawPie returns true,
        // indicating that all the labels fit, or we try too many times.

        do {
            if (attempts > 0) {
                maxRadius *= REDRAW_SHRINK;
            }
            attempts += 1;
            clear();
            if (options.series.pie.tilt <= 0.8) {
                drawShadow();
            }
        } while (!drawPie() && attempts < REDRAW_ATTEMPTS)

        if (attempts >= REDRAW_ATTEMPTS) {
            clear();
            //target.prepend("<div class='error'>Could not draw pie with labels contained inside canvas</div>");
        }

        if (plot.setSeries && plot.insertLegend) {
            plot.setSeries(slices);
            plot.insertLegend();
        }

        // we're actually done at this point, just defining internal functions at this point

        function clear() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            target.children().filter(".pieLabel, .pieLabelBackground").remove();
        }

        function drawShadow() {

            var shadowLeft = options.series.pie.shadow.left;
            var shadowTop = options.series.pie.shadow.top;
            var edge = 10;
            var alpha = options.series.pie.shadow.alpha;
            var radius = options.series.pie.radius > 1 ? options.series.pie.radius : maxRadius * options.series.pie.radius;

            if (radius >= canvasWidth / 2 - shadowLeft || radius * options.series.pie.tilt >= canvasHeight / 2 - shadowTop || radius <= edge) {
                return; // shadow would be outside canvas, so don't draw it
            }

            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(shadowLeft,shadowTop);
            ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

            // center and rotate to starting position

            ctx.translate(centerLeft,centerTop);
            ctx.scale(1, options.series.pie.tilt);

            //radius -= edge;

            for (var i = 1; i <= edge; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.fill();
                radius -= i;
            }

            ctx.restore();
        }

        function drawPie() {

            var startAngle = Math.PI * options.series.pie.startAngle;
            var radius = options.series.pie.radius > 1 ? options.series.pie.radius : maxRadius * options.series.pie.radius;

            // center and rotate to starting position

            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(centerLeft,centerTop);
            ctx.scale(1, options.series.pie.tilt);
            //ctx.rotate(startAngle); // start at top; -- This doesn't work properly in Opera

            // draw slices

            ctx.save();
            var currentAngle = startAngle;
            for (var i = 0; i < slices.length; ++i) {
                slices[i].startAngle = currentAngle;
                drawSlice(slices[i].angle, slices[i].color, true);
            }
            ctx.restore();

            // draw slice outlines

            if (options.series.pie.stroke.width > 0) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.lineWidth = options.series.pie.stroke.width;
                currentAngle = startAngle;
                for (var i = 0; i < slices.length; ++i) {
                    drawSlice(slices[i].angle, options.series.pie.stroke.color, false);
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }

            // draw donut hole

            drawDonutHole(ctx);

            ctx.restore();

            // Draw the labels, returning true if they fit within the plot

            if (options.series.pie.label.show) {
                return drawLabels();
            } else return true;

            function drawSlice(angle, color, fill) {

                if (angle <= 0 || isNaN(angle)) {
                    return;
                }

                if (fill) {
                    //ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    ctx.fillStyle = getColorOrGradient(options.series.pie.gradient, plot.height(), 0, color, options.series.pie.gradient.radial && radius);

                } else {
                    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                }

                ctx.beginPath();
                if (Math.abs(angle - Math.PI * 2) > 0.000000001) {
                    ctx.moveTo(0, 0); // Center of the pie
                }

                //ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, angle, false); // This doesn't work properly in Opera
                ctx.arc(0, 0, radius,currentAngle, currentAngle + angle / 2, false);
                ctx.arc(0, 0, radius,currentAngle + angle / 2, currentAngle + angle, false);
                ctx.closePath();
                //ctx.rotate(angle); // This doesn't work properly in Opera
                currentAngle += angle;

                if (fill) {
                    ctx.fill();
                } else {
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }

            function getColorOrGradient(spec, bottom, top, defaultColor, radius) {
                // Most of this code is copied from the function with the
                // same name in jquery.flot.js.  I therefore believe that
                // this (common) code should be restructured to avoid
                // duplication of errors and an increase in maintenance
                // efforts.  However, I hope that one of the project
                // maintainers can do that.
                if (typeof spec === 'string') {
                    return spec;
                } else if ((spec === null) || (spec.colors === null)) {
                    return defaultColor;
                } else {
                    // assume this is a gradient spec; IE currently only
                    // supports a simple vertical gradient properly, so that's
                    // what we support too
                    var gradient;

                    if (radius) {
                        gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, radius);
                    } else {
                        gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, top, 0, bottom);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0, l = spec.colors.length; i < l; ++i) {
                        var c = spec.colors[i];
                        if (typeof c !== 'string') {
                            var co = $.color.parse(defaultColor);
                            if (c.brightness != null)
                                co = co.scale('rgb', c.brightness);
                            if (c.opacity != null)
                                co.a *= c.opacity;
                            c = co.toString();
                        }
                        gradient.addColorStop(i / (l - 1), c);
                    }

                    return gradient;
                }
            }

            function drawLabels() {
                var labels = [];

                var currentAngle = startAngle;
                var radius = options.series.pie.label.radius > 1 ? options.series.pie.label.radius : maxRadius * options.series.pie.label.radius;

                for (var i = 0; i < slices.length; ++i) {
                    if (slices[i].percent >= options.series.pie.label.threshold * 100) {
                        if (!drawLabel(slices[i], currentAngle, i)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    currentAngle += slices[i].angle;
                }

                return true;

                function drawLabel(slice, startAngle, index) {

                    if (slice.data[0][1] == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    // format label text

                    var lf = options.legend.labelFormatter, text, plf = options.series.pie.label.formatter;

                    if (lf) {
                        text = lf(slice.label, slice);
                    } else {
                        text = slice.label;
                    }

                    if (plf) {
                        text = plf(text, slice);
                    }

                    var halfAngle = ((startAngle + slice.angle) + startAngle) / 2;
                    var x = centerLeft + Math.round(Math.cos(halfAngle) * radius);
                    var y = centerTop + Math.round(Math.sin(halfAngle) * radius) * options.series.pie.tilt;

                    var html = "<span class='pieLabel' id='pieLabel" + index + "' style='position:absolute;top:" + y + "px;left:" + x + "px;'>" + text + "</span>";
                    target.append(html);

                    var label = target.children("#pieLabel" + index);
                    var labelTop = (y - label.height() / 2);
                    var labelLeft = (x - label.width() / 2);

                    label.css("top", labelTop);
                    label.css("left", labelLeft);

                    // check to make sure that the label doesn't overlap one of the other labels
                    var label_pos = getPositions(label);
                    for(var j=0; j<labels.length; j++)
                    {
                        var tmpPos = getPositions(labels[j]);
                        var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(label_pos[0], tmpPos[0]);
                        var verticalMatch = comparePositions(label_pos[1], tmpPos[1]);
                        var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;
                        if(match)
                        {
                            var newTop = tmpPos[1][0] - (label.height() +1 );
                            label.css('top', newTop);
                            labelTop = newTop;
                        }
                    }

                    function getPositions(box) {
                        var $box = $(box);
                        var pos = $box.position();
                        var width = $box.width();
                        var height = $box.height();
                        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
                    }

                    function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
                        var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
                        var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
                        return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
                    }

                    labels.push(label);
                    // check to make sure that the label is not outside the canvas

                    if (0 - labelTop > 0 || 0 - labelLeft > 0 || canvasHeight - (labelTop + label.height()) < 0 || canvasWidth - (labelLeft + label.width()) < 0) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (options.series.pie.label.background.opacity != 0) {

                        // put in the transparent background separately to avoid blended labels and label boxes

                        var c = options.series.pie.label.background.color;

                        if (c == null) {
                            c = slice.color;
                        }

                        var pos = "top:" + labelTop + "px;left:" + labelLeft + "px;";
                        $("<div class='pieLabelBackground' style='position:absolute;width:" + label.width() + "px;height:" + label.height() + "px;" + pos + "background-color:" + c + ";'></div>")
                            .css("opacity", options.series.pie.label.background.opacity)
                            .insertBefore(label);
                    }

                    return true;
                } // end individual label function
            } // end drawLabels function
        } // end drawPie function
    } // end draw function

    // Placed here because it needs to be accessed from multiple locations

    function drawDonutHole(layer) {
        if (options.series.pie.innerRadius > 0) {

            // subtract the center

            layer.save();
            var innerRadius = options.series.pie.innerRadius > 1 ? options.series.pie.innerRadius : maxRadius * options.series.pie.innerRadius;
            layer.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // this does not work with excanvas, but it will fall back to using the stroke color
            layer.beginPath();
            layer.fillStyle = options.series.pie.stroke.color;
            layer.arc(0, 0, innerRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            layer.fill();
            layer.closePath();
            layer.restore();

            // add inner stroke

            layer.save();
            layer.beginPath();
            layer.strokeStyle = options.series.pie.stroke.color;
            layer.arc(0, 0, innerRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            layer.stroke();
            layer.closePath();
            layer.restore();

            // TODO: add extra shadow inside hole (with a mask) if the pie is tilted.
        }
    }

    //-- Additional Interactive related functions --

    function isPointInPoly(poly, pt) {
        for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
            ((poly[i][1] <= pt[1] && pt[1] < poly[j][1]) || (poly[j][1] <= pt[1] && pt[1]< poly[i][1]))
            && (pt[0] < (poly[j][0] - poly[i][0]) * (pt[1] - poly[i][1]) / (poly[j][1] - poly[i][1]) + poly[i][0])
            && (c = !c);
        return c;
    }

    function findNearbySlice(mouseX, mouseY) {

        var slices = plot.getData(),
            options = plot.getOptions(),
            radius = options.series.pie.radius > 1 ? options.series.pie.radius : maxRadius * options.series.pie.radius,
            x, y;

        for (var i = 0; i < slices.length; ++i) {

            var s = slices[i];

            if (s.pie.show) {

                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0); // Center of the pie
                //ctx.scale(1, options.series.pie.tilt);    // this actually seems to break everything when here.
                ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, s.startAngle, s.startAngle + s.angle / 2, false);
                ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, s.startAngle + s.angle / 2, s.startAngle + s.angle, false);
                ctx.closePath();
                x = mouseX - centerLeft;
                y = mouseY - centerTop;

                if (ctx.isPointInPath) {
                    if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX - centerLeft, mouseY - centerTop)) {
                        ctx.restore();
                        return {
                            datapoint: [s.percent, s.data],
                            dataIndex: 0,
                            series: s,
                            seriesIndex: i
                        };
                    }
                } else {

                    // excanvas for IE doesn;t support isPointInPath, this is a workaround.

                    var p1X = radius * Math.cos(s.startAngle),
                        p1Y = radius * Math.sin(s.startAngle),
                        p2X = radius * Math.cos(s.startAngle + s.angle / 4),
                        p2Y = radius * Math.sin(s.startAngle + s.angle / 4),
                        p3X = radius * Math.cos(s.startAngle + s.angle / 2),
                        p3Y = radius * Math.sin(s.startAngle + s.angle / 2),
                        p4X = radius * Math.cos(s.startAngle + s.angle / 1.5),
                        p4Y = radius * Math.sin(s.startAngle + s.angle / 1.5),
                        p5X = radius * Math.cos(s.startAngle + s.angle),
                        p5Y = radius * Math.sin(s.startAngle + s.angle),
                        arrPoly = [[0, 0], [p1X, p1Y], [p2X, p2Y], [p3X, p3Y], [p4X, p4Y], [p5X, p5Y]],
                        arrPoint = [x, y];

                    // TODO: perhaps do some mathmatical trickery here with the Y-coordinate to compensate for pie tilt?

                    if (isPointInPoly(arrPoly, arrPoint)) {
                        ctx.restore();
                        return {
                            datapoint: [s.percent, s.data],
                            dataIndex: 0,
                            series: s,
                            seriesIndex: i
                        };
                    }
                }

                ctx.restore();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    function onMouseMove(e) {
        triggerClickHoverEvent("plothover", e);
    }

    function onClick(e) {
        triggerClickHoverEvent("plotclick", e);
    }

    // trigger click or hover event (they send the same parameters so we share their code)

    function triggerClickHoverEvent(eventname, e) {

        var offset = plot.offset();
        var canvasX = parseInt(e.pageX - offset.left);
        var canvasY =  parseInt(e.pageY - offset.top);
        var item = findNearbySlice(canvasX, canvasY);

        if (options.grid.autoHighlight) {

            // clear auto-highlights

            for (var i = 0; i < highlights.length; ++i) {
                var h = highlights[i];
                if (h.auto == eventname && !(item && h.series == item.series)) {
                    unhighlight(h.series);
                }
            }
        }

        // highlight the slice

        if (item) {
            highlight(item.series, eventname);
        }

        // trigger any hover bind events

        var pos = { pageX: e.pageX, pageY: e.pageY };
        target.trigger(eventname, [pos, item]);
    }

    function highlight(s, auto) {
        //if (typeof s == "number") {
        //  s = series[s];
        //}

        var i = indexOfHighlight(s);

        if (i == -1) {
            highlights.push({ series: s, auto: auto });
            plot.triggerRedrawOverlay();
        } else if (!auto) {
            highlights[i].auto = false;
        }
    }

    function unhighlight(s) {
        if (s == null) {
            highlights = [];
            plot.triggerRedrawOverlay();
        }

        //if (typeof s == "number") {
        //  s = series[s];
        //}

        var i = indexOfHighlight(s);

        if (i != -1) {
            highlights.splice(i, 1);
            plot.triggerRedrawOverlay();
        }
    }

    function indexOfHighlight(s) {
        for (var i = 0; i < highlights.length; ++i) {
            var h = highlights[i];
            if (h.series == s)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    function drawOverlay(plot, octx) {

        var options = plot.getOptions();

        var radius = options.series.pie.radius > 1 ? options.series.pie.radius : maxRadius * options.series.pie.radius;

        octx.save();
        octx.translate(centerLeft, centerTop);
        octx.scale(1, options.series.pie.tilt);

        for (var i = 0; i < highlights.length; ++i) {
            drawHighlight(highlights[i].series);
        }

        drawDonutHole(octx);

        octx.restore();

        function drawHighlight(series) {

            if (series.angle <= 0 || isNaN(series.angle)) {
                return;
            }

            //octx.fillStyle = parseColor(options.series.pie.highlight.color).scale(null, null, null, options.series.pie.highlight.opacity).toString();
            octx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + options.series.pie.highlight.opacity + ")"; // this is temporary until we have access to parseColor
            octx.beginPath();
            if (Math.abs(series.angle - Math.PI * 2) > 0.000000001) {
                octx.moveTo(0, 0); // Center of the pie
            }
            octx.arc(0, 0, radius, series.startAngle, series.startAngle + series.angle / 2, false);
            octx.arc(0, 0, radius, series.startAngle + series.angle / 2, series.startAngle + series.angle, false);
            octx.closePath();
            octx.fill();
        }
    }
} // end init (plugin body)

// define pie specific options and their default values

var options = {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: false,
            radius: "auto", // actual radius of the visible pie (based on full calculated radius if <=1, or hard pixel value)
            innerRadius: 0, /* for donut */
            startAngle: 3/2,
            tilt: 1,
            shadow: {
                left: 5,    // shadow left offset
                top: 15,    // shadow top offset
                alpha: 0.02 // shadow alpha
            },
            offset: {
                top: 0,
                left: "auto"
            },
            stroke: {
                color: "#fff",
                width: 1
            },
            label: {
                show: "auto",
                formatter: function(label, slice) {
                    return "<div style='font-size:x-small;text-align:center;padding:2px;color:" + slice.color + ";'>" + label + "<br/>" + Math.round(slice.percent) + "%</div>";
                },  // formatter function
                radius: 1,  // radius at which to place the labels (based on full calculated radius if <=1, or hard pixel value)
                background: {
                    color: null,
                    opacity: 0
                },
                threshold: 0    // percentage at which to hide the label (i.e. the slice is too narrow)
            },
            combine: {
                threshold: -1,  // percentage at which to combine little slices into one larger slice
                color: null,    // color to give the new slice (auto-generated if null)
                label: "Other"  // label to give the new slice
            },
            highlight: {
                //color: "#fff",        // will add this functionality once parseColor is available
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            gradient: {
                radial: true, // boolean, indicating radial or linear gradient
                colors: null // e.g., [{opacity: 0.1, brightness: 1.0}, {opacity: 1.0, brightness: 1.0}]
            }
        }
    }
};

$.plot.plugins.push({
    init: init,
    options: options,
    name: "pie",
    version: "1.1"
});

})(jQuery);
```

[full Code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/C4pt4inC4nn4bis/L2ybgxpt/)